# No puedo visualizar un Código QR en un certificado cundo subo mi proyecto a Hostinger

Tags: php, dompdf

Estoy usando la librería DomPDF para crear una certificación que tiene un código QR para hacer la validación de la misma; En mi localhost todo funciona de forma correcta pero cuando lo subo mi proyecto a Hostinger el PDF no me muestra la imagen con el código QR pero probé con otras imágenes que no son código QR y si me las muestra.

Answer (score 0):

En tu servidor  de Hostinger has de verificar que cumplas estos requisitos:

PHP versión 7.1 o superior

extensión DOM

Extensión MBString

php-font-lib

php-svg-lib

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda, Chema.